# aws s3 ls exact match

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to verify that file AdHocQuery.js exists in s3-url using following command.

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://web-content-test/application/AdHocQuery.js --recursive --summarize
2013-06-11 20:25:12 1136257 AdHocQuery.js
2013-06-11 20:25:13 7524785 AdHocQuery.js.remove_oldvalue
```

but here, it is also returning .remove_oldvalue as well, which is kind of false-positive. I am looking for ways where I can check certain file exists without checking .masks.

Comment: You can use [head-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html) to check if key exist, but not sure if this is what you want to do?

Comment: I think the problem is that `aws s3 ls --recursive` is accepting the path as a Prefix, rather than an absolute Key. What happens if you exclude `--recursive`? Alternatively, I agree with @Marcin that using `aws s3api head-object` would work, since it accepts a Key rather than a recursive Prefix.

Comment: No, even without `--recursive` multiple objects will be returned if they start with the name that is given to `aws s3 ls`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked! Thank you for suggesting in comments!

```
object_exists=$(aws s3api head-object --bucket $bucket --key $key || true)
if [ -z "$object_exists" ]; then
  echo "it does not exist"
else
  echo "it exists"
fi
```